# Kill application at a fixed time

Tags: python, timer, pyqt4, terminate

I am using PyQt4 to develop an application. I want to terminate this application at a fixed time in the day (say 11 PM). Before killing the application, I want to save a few things. I am doing something as follows:

```
def main():
    app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here MainWindow is defined as follows:

```
class MainWindow(PyQt4.QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...
```

I am not sure how to go about it. Can someone point me in the right direction (or possibly provide a code snippet) to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the current time has passed a predetermined time (you can't really check if the times are *equal*) and have your `MainWindow` close itself:

```
if datetime.datetime.now().time() > datetime.time(hour = 23):
    self.close()
```

Then intercept the close event by overloading `closeEvent` and do your saving there:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    # do some stuff
    event.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single-shot timer to call the `close()` slot of the main window at a fixed time, and then use the `closeEvent` to save your data.

Care must be taken to ensure the timer is not given a negative, or zero interval. This could happen if the application was started at, say, 12pm and was set to finish at 11pm (i.e. on the following day).

Here's a simple demo script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        time = QtCore.QTime(23, 0, 0)
        now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        then = QtCore.QDateTime(now.date(), time)
        if now.time() > then.time():
            then = then.addDays(1)
        print('started at: %s' % now.toString())
        msec = now.msecsTo(then)
        if msec > 0:
            print('finishing at: %s' % then.toString())
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(msec, self.close)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('saving at: %s' % QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
        # if saving failed, you could prevent closure
        # by calling event.ignore() here

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```